# JavaFX: hostservices.showDocument() bad perfomance

Tags: java, javafx

For a JavaFX standalone desktop application I am using hostservices.showDocument() to open URLs in the default web browser. But in most cases if I try to open URLs with this method, it takes a lot of time (20-30 secs) until browser opens. Is there any known performance bug regarding this or does anyone have the same problem? I don't have this issue with awt.Desktop.getDesktop.browse() (browser opens immediately) but I don't want to use AWT stack in a JavaFX application.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using as part of your question, please?

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize there was a FX class for web access.  Is there a reason why using the "AWT stack" is an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say where your application goes awry, but it may help to study the problem in isolation. Try the complete example below to help you isolate the latency. It opens *at least* as fast as `Desktop#browse()` on my platform, i.e. within a second.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37839898/230513
 */
public class Test extends Application {

    private final HostServices services = this.getHostServices();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        Button button = new Button("Example");
        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            services.showDocument("http://example.com/");
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Addendum: Using the isolated test case, @Joey was able to determine that the problem

- *Did* occur with `showDocument()`; did *not* occur with direct browser access.
- *Did* occur with long URLs; did *not* occur with short URLs.
- *Did* occur on one computer; did *not* occur on others.

The culprit appears to be GDA G Data InternetSecurity "behavioral analysis proxy," `avkbap64.exe`, discussed [here](http://www.rokop-security.de/index.php?showtopic=23900&st=100).

Comment: Not on my pc (windows 10) but what i found out now is that the urls I try to open are very long. If i try to open a short url like http://amazon.de its opening very fast. But long URL for example "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00N9O8NPS/ref=br_asw_pdt-5?pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=24XXRB5870FJ9K6EYW51&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=f174871c-54ea-44ff-a8bb-64ea261617fa&pf_rd_i=desktop" takes very long like I described

Comment: Just tested the above code on my machine (Windows 8.1, default browser is Firefox) and it worked fine. Opens almost immediately, with the given URL and with both the URLs provided by the OP in the comment above.

Comment: Seems I am the only one with that problem. Maybe there is something wrong with my pc. But what can cause that behavavior?

Comment: @Joey: I'm not sure. I got prompt results with Windows 10, Chrome with even longer URLs. Is your long URL delay obtained with your application or the isolated `Test` above?

Comment: @trashgod with both

Comment: @Joey: To distinguish between browser and application, what happens when you open the long URL directly in the default browser? What happens when you choose a different default browser?

Comment: @trashgod: if I try to open the url directly its very quick. The problem appears in every browser (tested with firefox, opera, edge, ie).

Comment: The `showDocument()` method delegates to a compiled, platform-dependent `HostServicesFactory`. Since it seems limited to your machine, have you been able to try another Windows installation?

Comment: I found out that my Antivirus (I am using G Data) is responsible for it. Since I tried everything else I uninstalled my Antivirus. After that it worked like expected. I installed it again, and the issue appeared again. Then I experimented with the Antivurs settings... If the option "behavioral analysis proxy" (hope that is the correct name, I don't have a english version, because I am not english) is deactivated, its working. But there is no option to set exceptions for that setting. Now I contacted G Data directly... Thanks to all people who tried to help me :)

Comment: @Joey: Well done! I've elaborated above, but you can also [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).